# Mass update passwords in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have looked at a lot of mass-assignment questions, and none of them seem to deal with the issue I have. I am dealing with a legacy system that has ~350k clear-text passwords stored in it. I am re-engineering the system for Laravel 4, so I need to utilize Laravel's password hashing system on all of these entries. I tried doing:

```
$users = User::where(DB::raw('length(password)'), '<', 60)->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($user->password);
    $user->save();
}
```

Which works, but was taking an outrageous amount of time, and I don't want to go about waiting for several days for all of these records to update. (DB is remote, so there's a lot of additional lag time in communication.)

I was hoping I could do something along the lines of:

```
DB::table('users')->where(DB::raw('length(password)'), '<', 60)
    ->update(['password'=>????]);
```

Per the Laravel docs, this looks like the syntax I'd use, but I have no idea what I would do with the ???? part.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
-Eric

Comment: =>Hash::make($user->password); ?

Comment: Where would $user come from?

Comment: Hmm you're right.. you're going to have to itterate after.. Ignore my comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through them - there is no other way. You need to calculate a unique salted hash for each cleartext password.

The reason it is taking "*an outrageous amount of time*" is because Hashing is computationally expensive. You dont notice this for 1-2 hashes. But you will for 350k hashes.

Its like Bitcoin mining - except your not getting paid this time.

Edit: also - if users *could* have had a password length >60 in 'clear text' in your old system - you still *must* hash those into a 60 length hash if you plan on using the Laravel Auth system - because it will auto hash the password when comparing it against the database.

Comment: Another reason is because the ORM is being used. Hydrating user objects just to access the columns as properties is wasteful. Similarly executing a save query on each iteration will slow it down

Comment: Thanks, that's sort of what I figured, but I was hoping there might even be a way to do a '->chunk(1000, function($user){$ids = [], $pws = [], DB::table->whereIn($ids)->update($pws);})' and compute 1000 at a whack, then assign all 1000 with a single update query. Will still be slow in processing, but will save ~.05s per query, which adds up fast.

Comment: Could you copy the table, or is it 'in use'? If you can copy it - slice it on 3-4 different computers, and have them run the hash, then put them all back onto the real server. Even if you did it on one computer 'locally' - then move the table back?

Comment: Hm, that may be an option. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering an old question, but have just come across almost an identical issue.

In order to not have three days of downtime, what I ended up doing was:

1. Temporarily having a password_tmp column which had the password in plain text
2. Extended EloquentUserProvider with my own LegacyUserProvider and replaced the validateCredentials method
3. If a user logged in and their password column was empty, it tested the password against password_tmp instead. If this was correct, it logged the user in and then hashed and saved the password
4. In the background, I had a set of queues running that went and grabbed users with a blank password column and hashing password_tmp
5. Then after a few days, when all old passwords were replaced, dropping password_tmp

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses `bcrypt` for hashing. `bcrypt` is specifically designed to be slow as a security measure - it prevents an attacker from brute forcing logins by trying millions or billions of passwords rapidly until you find a match.